# Cypress component tests warning "Encountered two children with the same key" when using fixture

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I'm trying to run a cypress unit test on a component that pulls in a list of items but only displays them one at a time. Each item has a button that when pressed, displays the next item, and hides the previous item and button.
In my unit test, when I iterate over my fixture data, I'm getting `Warning: Encountered two children with the same key` from my test with the for loop.
[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0DE6.png)

When I use a .only on the second test, the warning does not show up, but when I run the entire file, it does, even though I'm generating the test data from the fixture in a beforeEach. This error does not show up in my component, just the cypress test.
Does anyone have any ideas why this warning shows up when I run the whole test file, and how I could resolve it?

```
describe('Some Component', () => {
  let data: SomeComponentData;
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.fixture('json_file').then((testData) => {
      data = testData;
      return data;
    });
  });
  it('some other test', () => {
    ...
  });
  it('displays each item in list', () => {
    cy.mount(<SomeComponent data={data} />);
    for (let i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
      cy.get('[data-cy="button"]').click();
      cy.contains(data.items[i].text)
     }
    });
  });
```

I've tried creating the fixture in each individual test, but I'm getting the same error. Wondering if this is relating to some sort of caching that occurs with fixtures in cypress?

Comment: It might be a problem with visibility. Cypress by default does not care about it, so even if a user only sees 1 element, actually the DOM might have more than one.

Comment: Yeah I think that makes sense. The cypress browser is rendering multiple components with the same key even though that's not the behavior within the app. I wonder if there's a way to not have all component test show up within a single browser, and just have them remounted after each test?